# Why does WinDBG show mismatched FileVersion in dump?

Tags: windbg, portable-executable, memory-dump, fileversioninfo, rsrc

**TL;DR**

Why does WinDBG `lmv`display two version info fields (when no other tool I know of does this) and under which circumstances can these fields differ?

---

Background: I have a live dump (from a deadlock) of our application. Symbols are loaded correctly and I was able to trace back the deadlock to Microsoft's `pdm.dll` ("Process Debug Manager" used for our vbscript engine).

I then wanted to check which version of this DLL was loaded in the session at the production site:

```
0:000> lmv m pdm
start    end        module name
51860000 518b8000   pdm      # (pdb symbols)          d:\symcache\pdm.pdb\7BE601EDE9234816B72B49DA4A25DF042\pdm.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: pdm.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG\pdm.dll
    Image name: pdm.dll
    Timestamp:        Tue Jul 29 16:46:11 2008 (488F2D33)
    CheckSum:         000663E0
    ImageSize:        00058000
??  File version:     9.0.30729.1
??  Product version:  9.0.30729.1
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Visual Studio .NET
    InternalName:     pdm.dll
    OriginalFilename: pdm.dll
??  ProductVersion:   7.10.3077
??  FileVersion:      7.10.3077
    FileDescription:  Process Debug Manager
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

As you can see, the file and product versions are displayed twice, but they are mismatched in the dump!

When I cross-check on my machine for (apparently, see the timestamp and checksum!) the same file for a running iexplore process:

```
0:043> lmv m pdm
start    end        module name
3efa0000 3eff8000   pdm        (pdb symbols)          c:\windows\symbols\martin-cache\pdm.pdb\415D0A165EB24613BC01CE516512062C2\pdm.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\pdm.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\pdm.dll
    Image name: pdm.dll
    Timestamp:        Tue Jul 29 16:46:11 2008 (488F2D33)
    CheckSum:         000663E0
    ImageSize:        00058000
    File version:     9.0.30729.1
    Product version:  9.0.30729.1
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008
    InternalName:     pdm.dll
    OriginalFilename: pdm.dll
    ProductVersion:   9.0.30729.1
    FileVersion:      9.0.30729.1 built by: SP
    FileDescription:  Process Debug Manager
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

the version infos match up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lmv  displays the strings which are defined in the resource file,

[image]

I don’t know why there is common to two set of File/Product versions names the same except some spaces.

```
0:041> lmv m kernel32
start    end        module name
753e0000 754f0000   kernel32   (deferred)             
    Image path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
    Image name: kernel32.dll
    Timestamp:        Fri Aug 02 03:53:25 2013 (51FB1115)
    CheckSum:         00111A9F
    ImageSize:        00110000
    File version:     6.1.7601.18229
    Product version:  6.1.7601.18229
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     kernel32
    OriginalFilename: kernel32
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.18229
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
```

In your case you have two different dll’s, look at the image file path.

```
Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG\
```

and

```
Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
```

They must have different strings in the resource section, winDbg can’t do anything but display it.
Since the time stamps are identical, one may have been tampered.

Comment: Ah. so the first version is from `FILEVERSION` and the second one is from `BLOCK "StringFileInfo"` - `VALUE "FileVersion"`. I was kinda blind to miss that. :-/

Comment: As for tampering - you can tamper the *CheckSum* ??? (Because that is also the same.)

Comment: I meant that maybe one is a copy of the other, hence the equal checksum, size & time, and then had one of the versions altered together with the ProductName.